# Cyclomatic complexity for some_method is too high

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following method in controller. When i run `lint` i get the error
`Cyclomatic complexity for some_method is too high`

I checked online about it and seems like it is the way i wrote the method. How could i rewrite this method so i dont get the lint error?

```
  def customer_order
    if params[:customer_id].present? && !params[:order_id].present?
      render_error :not_found, 'No info found for given customer id' \
      unless @info.customer_id == params[:customer_id]
    elsif params[:order_id].present? && !params[:customer_id].present?
      render_error :not_found, 'No info found for given order id' \
      unless @info.order_id == params[:order_id]
    elsif params[:customer_id].present? && params[:order_id].present?
      render_error :not_found, 'No info found for given customer id and order id’ \
        unless @info.customer_id == params[:customer_id] &&
               @info.order_id == params[:order_id]
    end
  end
```

Comment: !params[:customer_id].present? is easier to read  as params[:customer_id].blank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yikes! It is too high!

This linting message essentially means you have so many `if` statements that it's hard for a developer to keep straight.

I would suggest refactoring the contents of each `if` statement into it's own method.

```
def customer_order
  if params[:customer_id].present? && !params[:order_id].present?
    no_order_error
  elsif params[:order_id].present? && !params[:customer_id].present?
    no_info_error
  ...
end

def no_order_error
  return if @info.customer_id == params[:customer_id]
  render_error :not_found, 'No info found for given customer id'
end

def no_info_error
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to make each of the conditionals their own method. As an example:

```
def customer_without_order(params)
  params[:customer_id].present? && !params[:order_id].present?
end
```

You may find that the conditionals that determine when you render an error warrant this treatment as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce some of the redundancy like so.

```
def customer_order
  msg = case [params[:customer_id].present?, params[:order_id].present?]
  when [true, false]
    @info.customer_id == params[:customer_id] ?
      nil : 'No info found for given customer id'
  when [false, true]
    @info.order_id == params[:order_id] ?
      nil : 'No info found for given order id'
  when [true, true]
    @info.customer_id == params[:customer_id] && @info.order_id == params[:order_id] ?
      nil : 'No info found for given customer id and order id’
  else
    nil
  end
  render_error(:not_found, msg) if msg
end
```